# Laravel Database Many to Many (Mysql) or keep Json in table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, laravel

I need an advice i am using laravel and im not sure if i should go many to many (mysql) or stay with Json which is encoded in table (rest of the code works fine), hopefuly i will be able to explain it correctly. So here goes, the user has to solve an exam which has questions, and questions change on a button click (every question is on the same div, content is changed on click with jquery) , so when user presses start it shows question with 3 (for example) radio boxes as answers from which one is correct. After the user selects answer form radio buttons and clicks next his answer (value) is stored in session and then the same div shows different question and so on. Once the user gets to the last question his answers are taken from Session and sent to an email. So now for the code part, Structure of exam table.

```
   Schema::create('exams', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
        $table->increments('id');
                    $table->string('title')->unique();
                    $table->text('questions_json'); //json encode see example below
                    $table->integer('duration');
                    $table->string('remember_token',64);
                    $table->timestamps();
        });
```

'questions_json' looks like (this is example)

```
[

   {
    "Question": "1+1?",
    "1": "11",
    "2": "2",
    "3": "-2",
    "correct": "2"
},
{
    "Question": "What is a rabbit?",
    "1": "Mammal",
    "2": "Vicious beast with sharp teeth",
    "3": "Cute thing",
    "correct": "1"
}

]
```

this is what i have now, so the controller reads this json text and removes correct from it and then sends json to jquery with question and answers which then generates form with radio buttons and next button.

But with this "admin" can not edit once the questions are in (have to put id in json so that he will be able to), but the only time admin would need to change this trough form is when he mistypes. So im not sure if i should leave it this way or change the db structure to many to many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing JSON data in your database is (almost) never a good idea. For example, as you noticed, it gets complicated when you want to edit the data.

I'd suggest a schema like this:

#### exams

- title
- duration
- remember_token

#### questions

- text
- exam_id

#### answers

- text
- question_id
- correct (boolean)

Then define the following **relations**:

#### Exam Model

```
public function questions(){
    return $this->hasMany('Question');
}
```

#### Question Model

```
public function answers(){
    return $this->hasMany('Answer');
}

public function exam(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Exam');
}
```

#### Answer Model

```
public function question(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Question');
}
```

More information about [Relations in the Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)

Comment: Taught as much, all tough json at the moment looks like an easier solution but in the long run it will cause problems if something will needed to be changed. Thank you for the schema this will help me a lot.